# Is there a faster way to delete the first x rows from a DBF?

Tags: database, performance, optimization, delete-row, dbf

I have been trying to use CDBFLite to delete records of a DBF file from records 1 to 5 million or so (in order to decrease the filesize). Due to factors beyond my control, this is something I will have to do every day. The filesize exceeds 2 GB.

However, it takes forever to run the delete commands. Is there a faster way to just eliminate the first X records of a DBF (and thus result in a smaller filesize) ?

Comment: Or is there a way to truncate from the top?

Comment: The file size could be a problem -- I seem to recall that the `dbf` standard doesn't support files larger than that.  I've written a Python dbf library and I'd be willing to tackle the problem, but I would need a copy of your database to test against.  Let me know if you are interested.  (No charge, in case anyone is concerned about that.)

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Ethan, if a .DBF file, it typically caps at standard 32-bit OS capacity of 2-gig per single file when it comes to .DBFs unless you are dealing with another software engine such as SyBase Database Advantage which can read/write to .DBF files and exceed the 2 gig capacity.

That said, the DBF standard format has a single character on each record as a "flag" that the record is deleted, yet still retains the space.  In order to reduce the size, you would need to PACK the file which actually REMOVES the deleted records and thus will reduce the file size back down.

Now Ethan has options via Python, and I via C#.net and using Microsoft Visual Foxpro OleDb Provider and can offer more, but don't know what you have access to.

If you have VFP (or dBASE) directly, then it should be as simple as getting to the command window and doing

```
USE [YourTable] exclusive
pack
```

But I would make a backup copy of the file first as simple precaution.

Comment: Comments to go along with down-votes are a good thing.  I see nothing wrong nor unhelpful about this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very rough outline using my [dbf package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf):

```
import dbf
import shutil

database = r'\some\path\to\database.dbf'
backup = r'\some\backup\path\database.backup.dbf')

# make backup copy
shutil.copy(database, backup)

# open copy
backup = dbf.Table(backup)

# overwrite original
database = backup.new(database)

# copy over the last xxx records
with dbf.Tables(backup, database):
    for record in backup[-10000:]:
        database.append(record)
```

I suspect copying over the last however many records you want will be quicker than packing.

Comment: I'll give this a shot and let you know

Comment: I forget my slice notation but doesn't [-10000:] mean the last 10000 records? Wouldn't I be needing [10000:] to say "copy over everything but the first 10000 records"?

Comment: Also would it take a long time to perform an append for each individual record? Is there a way to just simultaneously kill off a huge chunk of records?

Comment: It seems to be taking an extremely long time unfortunately :(

Comment: @MyNameIsKhan: yes, `[-10000:]` means the last 10,000 records.  The code is selecting which records to copy, not which to omit.

Comment: In my case I was trying to copy over everything past row X (the same as "deleting the first X rows"), which I guess would be [-(totRows-x):] or something

Comment: @MyNameIsKhan: That slice looks right.  Did it ever finish?

Comment: It did not -- it was still running so I stopped it after a few hours.

Comment: @MyNameIsKhan: I uploaded a new version to PyPI that uses a sparse container internally; this may help with that very large file.